# Import p12 identity into application via handleOpenURL as email attachment

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

My application imports an identity from a p12 file for authenticating requests to a server.

This is working by document exchange with iTunes and loading the file from the filesystem.

Renaming the p12 file with my own filename extension is also working fine to import the file via email.

My question is, if it is possible to register for the p12 filename extension so renaming the file is not necessary any more. Registering for general file extensions is possible. Here is a list for the UTIs available by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Unfortunately p12 is missing in the list. Was anyone able to achieve this or does anyone know the UTI identifier for p12 files?

By the way: Exporting p12 as own file extension does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find UTI using this code:

```
CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, CFSTR("p12"), NULL);
```

The result will be:
**com.rsa.pkcs-12**

I tried to use this UTI to register as viewer, but it seems like Apple doesn't want anyone except them to be able to handle open of *.p12. Mail doesn't allow "Open In" - it opens p12 in Settings. I tried to open p12 via "Open In" from another application and that doesn't work too, nevertheless I've registered p12 UTI in my application's plist.